# RESTful api in Django using inbult view in Django, without creating 2 urls

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I've decent experience in Function based view in Django and now I'm trying to use Class based View. although I'm able to solve problems but I'm not sure about standard, I'mean if I'm doing it right or wrong, what you guyz(Django developers) follow.

More details about problem is here-

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import View

class InvoiceTransaction(View):

    def __init__(self):
        super(InvoiceTransaction, self).__init__()

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(InvoiceTransaction, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        invoiceid = kwargs.get('invoiceid')
        # here I have invoiceid, which is I'm passing through url paramaeters(see urls.py file)
        # based on invoice, I can decide what type of GET requests it is
        # whether user is asking for a single resource or all resource, right?
        if invoiceid:
             invoice = [Invoice.objects.get(id=invoiceid)]
        else:
             invoice = Invoice.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some stuff
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from invoice import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^invoices/$', views.InvoiceTransaction.as_view()),
    (r'^invoices/(?P<invoiceid>.*)/$', views.InvoiceTransaction.as_view()),
)
```

I followed this tutorial https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-rest-framework-class-based-views/

So my problem is that I'm creating two lines(urls) in urls.py file for a single request to determine the type of GET request. is there any other or better way to do this. how can I create a restful api using view and without creating 2 urls.

PS: feel free to suggest improvement/changes in above code as I'm newbie to this thing. it could be if I'm using dispatch method wrongly or idont really need **init** method, anything you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern, this should work for both urls -

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^invoices(/(?P<invoiceid>\d+)){,1}/$', views.InvoiceTransaction.as_view()),
)
```

This makes the whole id block optional but only one can be there at most.

BTW, `.*` is not quite right for id, better to use `\d+`

You can verify at pythex.org.

[image]

**EDIT:** with `^invoice(/(?P<invoice_type>.*)){,1}/$`

[image]

Comment: Nice :) but it would be great if you can explain this regex, as I'm not much comfortable with regex, how double small brackets and curly brackets are working?

Comment: the outer brackets is to make the full block optional or max 1 (notice the `{,1}` following it), this allows `invoice/`, and if the block is present then `invoice/10/`, since max 1 of the optional block is supported `invoice/10/5/` is invalid.

Comment: but `^invoice(/(?P<invoice_type>.*)){,1}/$` not working? can you please suggest what is wrong with this? `invoice_type` is a string(will be matched with predefined words in my view)

Comment: Who says not working? I have added another screen shot for it. Check it out.

Comment: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` I get this when I make this kind of url patterns, for the one you have written in your answer. what could be the reason. if I hit this url using POSTMAN or some other API emulator it works but django admin panel doesn't open and throw above error

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the first pattern and remove the ending slash from the second pattern.
So, your urlpatterns become

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^invoices/(?P<invoiceid>.*)$', views.InvoiceTransaction.as_view()),
)
```

This is because you are already using `.*` in the regex instead of `.+`, invoiceid that you receive can be empty.
But the compulsory end slash in your regex is preventing that from happening. In simpler terms, you already had the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As REST states that the system must talk only in terms of nouns and verbs.

The verbs that are applicable in a RESTful architecture are:

```
GET
POST
PUT
PATCH
DELETE
```

And the 2 urls, that any resource representation for a RESTful system are :

```
invoice/$
invoice/(?P<pk>\d+)/$
```

Let's have a look at the View which handles the urls without the pk.Let's call this view `InvoiceListCreateView`. Now, `InvoiceListCreateView` should only cater to GET and POST requests. It should not allow `PUT, PATCH and DELETE` requests. Why?

You can edit/delete only the existing objects and all the existing objects in your db ought to have an id associated with them. So, when I `GET` the `ListCreateView`, I get the list of all the Invoices existing in the database. When I `POST` to the `ListCreateView` , I should be able to insert a new entry into the `Invoice` table of the database.

Now, the url with the id appended to it. Let's call it `RetrieveUpdateDeleteView`. As the name suggests, the view should be able to perform the 3 functions namely, `RETRIEVE`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. And all these operations can be performed on the already existing objects for which the id will be present in the url kwargs.

When I `GET` the `RetrieveUpdateDeleteView`, I must get the object for that `id` provided in the url kwargs. Similarly, `PUT` and `PATCH` should update the object with the data sent by the user. And `DELETE` should delete the object from the database.

This is how I plan out the `REST` architecture.